# Check to see if a variable in a shell string begins with something

Tags: shell

I have a variable in my shell script called `$FOLDER`, and I want to check to see if `$FOLDER` begins with either `/` or `./`. I don't want `build` to trigger it, but I do want either `/build` or `./build` to work.

My attempt doesn't seem to be working, where am I going wrong?

```
if [[ $FOLDER == "/"* ]] || [[ $FOLDER == "./"* ]]
  then
  echo "Matched"
  exit 1
fi
```

Comment: So: extract the first character from the string and compare it. Then extract first two characters and compare them. Also always quote your variables. Never `$FOLDER`, always `"$FOLDER"`.

Comment: I'm not really sure how to do what you're suggesting - I also need to be sure that it matches either `/` or `./`, I don't want `.build` to trigger it for instance.

Comment: @KamilCuk The (lack of) quoting is fine when it's the left-hand argument inside `[[ ... ]]`.

Comment: What you have is fine if you are actually using `bash`.

Comment: @JamesIves : Note that `[[ ... ]]` is not valid in a POSIX shell.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `case`:

```
case "$FOLDER" in
/*|./*) echo "matched"
esac
```

Another way is to extract the substrings:

```
if [ "${FOLDER:0:1}" = "/" -o "${FOLDER:0:2}" = "./" ]; then
   echo "matched"
fi
```

- `${FOLDER:0:1}` extract one character from position 0 from the string.
- Similar `${FOLDER:0:2}` extracts two characters
- Always quote your variable expansions.
- `-o` is a mnemonic from `or`

Comment: `-o` is obsolete; use `[ ... ] || [ ... ]` instead. But if `${...:x:y}` is available, then it's almost certainly the case that better pattern-matching alternatives are available as well.

Comment: There's also no need to quote the expansion for `case`, as it is not subject to word-splitting or pathname expansion in that context.